# Stylus css Javascript library, is it possible to have global libraries to be used by small templates?

Tags: stylus

I have used Less css for quite some time, but mostly on the server side.

I am considering switching to the client side to possibly enable developers to make use of functions and already declared classes.

But for a small template, it should not need to include or import another file, which probably leads to the parser parsing that file over and over again.

Is it possible to declare a stylus file as global to be rendered only once, and imported, or even better implictly make functions in one available to others?

The purpose is to not have imported resources be reparsed for each small addition or component in need to use useful declared global functions ( such as .rounded-corners() .flex() and what not )

Related: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443904/lesscss-javascript-library-is-it-possible-to-have-global-libraries-to-be-used-b?noredirect=1#comment52788339_32443904 (I might consider a switch to either)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "client-side" in this scenario. Are you not generating css files on a build-step, or command line?

Comment: No, i want to do it client side, as a page is generated by js code, is this not possible?

Comment: It's possible though I can't understand why this is a desired approach. You would have to render the css file using the stylus JS api, then inject a stylesheet. That's so much effort and pageload time wasted just for syntactic sugar. I would highly recommend building your css using a build tool like `gulp-stylus` or even just `stylus --watch`. That way you can have globals, modules etc.

Comment: Build tools like webpack are designed exactly for this purpose as well. https://webpack.github.io/

Comment: I'm agree with @azium. First of all, are you understand that with client-side rendering each user of your application need to download and execute JS code + download and parse Stylus code and only after that something is being showed on the screen? And, secondly,  client-side version of Stylus is not so powerful as Less (e.g. you can't use imports, you can't declare stylesheets in HTML etc.). The client-side version of Stylus is not recommended to use in production, It was made only for development and sites like Codepen/JSBin.

Comment: The only "good" reason I can think of to do this is if you are going to have the `Stylus file to be heavily customized client-side via JS`. Although it may also be useful if the `(size of the Stylus + JS) is much less than (size of css file)`, which may the case if there's sufficient use of iteration and mixins, though that's probably a sign of a bigger issue elsewhere. Still it seems pretty iffy.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I know that stylus is not suitable for this.